# Divisor Functions

Tags: number-theory

http://www.positiveintegers.org/IntegerTables/1-100

Why is it that the Divisor Function less the Restricted Divisor Function is sequential, 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc.

Comment: Because $\sigma(N) = N + s(N)$

Answer (score 0):

The divisor function adds up all numbers that divide $n$ *including* itself; the restricted divisor function adds up all numbers that divide $n$ *excluding* itself.  So $\sigma(12)=1+2+3+4+6+12=28$ and $s(12)=1+2+3+4+6=16$, and they differ by 12 because one includes the 12 and the other does not.

Comment: Ah, wonderful. Sorry for asking the obvious. The other wonderful thing is that looking at the list up to 10,000 lonely deficient primes are surrounded by abundant numbers as if nature is trying to balance itself out.

Answer (score 0):

Divisor function: sum of all divisors including n.

Strict divisor function: sum of all divisors except n.

Divisor minus strict divisor: (sum of all divisors including n) minus (the sum of all divisors excluding n) =n.

Or $\sigma (n)=1+d_1+....+d_m+n $

And $s (n)=1+d_1+....+d_m $

So $\sigma (n)-s (n)=(1+d_1+....+d_m+ n) - (1+d_1+....+d_m)=n $